# Connecting external css to html

Tags: python, html, css, web

I am trying to connect some CSS code to some html code. This code is part of a bigger project that's why I imported a lot of stuff at the top but I am stuck on this simple step for some reason. Whenever I run my code it shows just the html on the website without the CSS. Sorry if this is a super obvious question I am still very new to coding.

I tried various ways of connecting it but it is not working.

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    page = """
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Stef LinkTREE</title>
  <link href="style.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>SPADE</p>

    </body>
    </html>

    """
    return page


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color:black;
}

p{
   font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I've never used Flask before, but in Django, we usually define a static_root directory. The static directory hosts the necessary assets such as your stylesheet. Perhaps this tutorial might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxgYYGxoPwY

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to HTML only, regardless which technology you are relying on, just do it static like './my-site/style/something.css' URL formation and it will always work. Note that the './' base always points to your HTML file URL location.

Diagnostics: Use network tab in browser developer tools and I am sure you will see your call to the CSS is failing for a wrong URL/location. Click the request to see where that URL points to and fix your HTML LINK code.